# Custom Span on MultiAutoCompleteTextView with some regex

Tags: android, regex, linkify, spannablestring, multiautocompletetextview

I want to do @ mentions in my app. 
When I start typing and notice '@' I show the suggestions from the multiview, I pick the one that I want and at the end I get this string as a result.

```
Hi @[John Snow](john-snow-id), I'm mention you in this edittext and then ill post you to the server.
```

Now, what I want to show in the multiview is.

```
Hi @John Snow I'm mention you in this edittext and then ill post you to the se
```

and what I want to send to the server is

```
Hi @[John Snow](john-snow-id), I'm mention you in this edittext and then ill post you to the server.
```

There can be multiple mentions. Any suggestions?

Comment: use Spannable.setSpan with ReplacementSpan